# Getting Run-time-error '-2147417848(80010108): Automation error. The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: vba

Getting error for below code:

```
Sub test()
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate ("http://www.siteminder.com" & ActiveCell)
    Do
            If ie.readyState = 4 Then
                ie.Visible = True
                Exit Do
        Else
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop

    ie.document.forms(0).all("User").Value = "me"
    ie.document.forms(0).all("Password").Value = "mypasssword"
    ie.document.forms(0).submit
End Sub
```

getting error for line:If ie.readyState = 4 Then

Answer (score 0):

With Internet Explorer, I prefer to use the InternetExplorerMedium object (I have just found it a bit more reliable in the past):

```
Dim ie as InternetExplorer

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
```

In any case, waiting for the browser can be the following:

```
Do While ie.readystate <> 4 Or ie.Busy
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Loop
```

Comment: Do While ie.readystate <> 4 Or ie.Busy
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Loop for those lines it giving intrerface is unknown error